# Enabling second byte (bit shifting)

Tags: php, bit-shift

How do I enable the second byte in 2 byte structure with help of bit shifting?

I want this result:

```
[x][x][x][x][x][x][x][x]|[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[----- second byte ----]|[----- first byte -----]
```

This is not working:

```
$options = 1 << 0xFF;
```

Comment: How are you defining this 2-byte structure? You're taking a 32-bit signed integer, and shifting the bits left 255 times

Comment: @MarkBaker What do you mean? I'm building an Excel writer and following the format specification.

Comment: @silkfire If that's the case then what you probably want to do is write out `0xff` followed by `0` (or swapped if Excel expects little-endian encoding), since I/O in PHP operates on bytes and not anything larger.

Comment: One byte is __8__ bits, not 255 bits

Comment: But for a 2-byte structure you need to learn about [pack()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)... look at how the PHPExcel Excel5 Writer works to see how to use bit manipulation to build your own Excel writer rather than to try and do it all from scratch

Comment: @MarkBaker I know about `pack`, I already completed the library last year but doing some touch-ups right now. Shifting is a powerful tool but a bit tricky to master.

Comment: @Silkfire - if you're going to Open Source your library, let me know the details and I'll add it to my list of Excel Readers/Writers for PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker It's closed source at the moment, I'm afraid it will be too popular otherwise.

Comment: Gee thanks, humiliation accepted - I was only trying to help

Comment: Well if you're interested we can discuss this outside SO. Here's the record I'm trying to perfect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906757(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I assume it's the last (options and xf) word that you're working on - you can email me if you want via [phpexcel.codeplex.com](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/team/view)

Comment: @MarkBaker I'll get back to you. Any email address?

Comment: There should be an email link on my profile page there: if not, you should be able to find it at https://github.com/MarkBaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value << number_of_bits
```

So

```
$options = 0xff << 8;
```

Alternatively,

```
$options = 0xff00;
```

since two hexadecimal digits form one byte.

Comment: I got myself confused there :) Thanks!